# Google Webmaster Tools won't index my site

Tags: indexing, search-engine, google-search-console

I discovered that my robots.txt file on my site is causing Google's Webmaster Tools to not  index my site properly. I tried and removed just about everything from the file (using WordPress so it will still generate it) but I keep getting the same error in their panel,

"Severe status problems were found on the site. - Check site status". And when I click on the site status it tells me that robots.txt is blocking my main page, which is not.

http://saturate.co/robots.txt - ideas?

Edit: Marking this as solved as it seems Webmaster Tools now accepted the site and is showing no errors.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO and webmastering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try adding `Disallow:` to the end of your file. So it looks like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

Comment: That was the exact setting I used earlier, same result.

Comment: You mean for the robots file?

Comment: Have you checked the robots file permissions?